# Open Modal from a form

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

Hi I have a link which once clicked opens a modal.  the problem is I want to pass a php variable to the modal so that i can then run a MYSQL Query.

This is my current link

```
  <?php echo "<a href=\"#modalForm\" class='modal-with-form btn btn-default'>Update Status</a>";?>
```

what i am trying to do is send a form like this.

```
     <form action="<a href='#modalForm'></a>" method="get" class="modal-with-form btn btn-default">
      <input type="hidden" name="usern" value="<?php echo "$usern"; ?>">
     <input name="" type="button">
    </form>
```

when i click the button the screen darkens but the form doesn't open.  Is it possible to do this this way?

Comment: It seems like your modal is unable to load properly. Open developer tools in your web browser (you can do that by pressing F12 key or clicking on a bug icon on top-right side of Chrome or Firefox). When you've opened it, browse to console and tell us what you see there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement it with jquery,

```
$('.modal-with-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Modal code here
});
```

and then replace the comment for "//Modal code here"  with your modal code

Comment: Hi do you mean my html and php which make up the modal form?

Answer (score 0):

I look for a while and i found this http://www.forosdelweb.com/f13/pasar-variable-php-ventana-modal-1059193/

Hope this help you my friend!! (Y)